# How to install .apk on multiple phones for testing

Tags: android, installation, apk, adb

Hi I am developing a cloud application for android. While developing its a torture to install apk on every phone after a single line change in code. Is there a way to install it through script. or maybe i can put apk to some web/ftp server and from there I can install it somehow on each phone. Atleast I dont have to connect every phone through USB every time.

Please Help

Comment: yes you can put your apk on a server and then keep the url booked marked in the devices and install it from there.

Comment: I swear that Square had released their code for a run-your-tests-on-N-attached-devices setup, but I can't find it right now...

Comment: that will be awesome .. please do let us know if you find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For our production purposes, we use Dropbox on our computers and our devices, copy APKs into it, then click from Dropbox from each of our phones.

edit: When I've had to programatically install APKs in the past, I used something like this (which I can't find where I got it from anymore):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" + "app.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is a cool idea. Is there a way to write a small application that can automatically install the updated apk files in dropbox folder. Is it possible for one application to install another apk?? If it is then I would love to explore that option.

Comment: @KanwarSaad, Yes, I think it's possible. You just have to sign both apps with the same certificate and be very careful about the application package names you're using. Basically the application package name of your installer needs to be nested one folder level above the other package name of the application it's installing I believe (and again, both need to be signed with the same certificate).

Comment: @KanwarSaad I edited my answer with how we've done it in the past. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to root some of those devices, you can do adb over wifi (unless they already have that option built-in).

You could also use a web server/gmail (or PushBullet for Jellybean-only devices) to deliver your apk to those devices, but that solution would still require a couple of additional steps from the user.

It's possible to install an application remotely over-the-air to your devices with your own google account without user intervention on the phone itself, but only if it's already published on Google Play. I suppose some of that process could be automated if you take a look at the new Google+ Sign-in api, and/or if you use a selenium script to trigger the installation from your desktop computer's web browser (because user authorization is still required through the web browser on the desktop itself, that's why you'd need Selenium to do that bit).